# No /camera/rgb/points, Natty

Tags: rviz, openni, ubuntu, ros-electric, ubuntu-natty

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi!
I install ROS-electric on fresh Natty(2.6.38-11-generic) with updates using this [tutorial](http://www.ros.org/wiki/electric/Installation/Ubuntu). Next, I try to launch openni_camera with this [sample](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_kinect).
Everything is normal, but in rviz there is no /camera/rgb/points topic. Where can be problem?
So, there are some details:

1. Logs from roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch - http://pastebin.com/z4YVUgEn
2. rviz's sreenshot - http://imageshack.us/f/51/screenshot0906201102235.png 
   Thanks for help!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11126/no-/camera/rgb/points,-natty/) by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on ROS Answers with karma: 546 on 2011-09-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) on 2011-09-06**:
Does /camera/rgb/points show up when you do rostopic list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm guessing that you followed the Diamondback instructions at [openni_camera](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_camera). I see that I somehow introduced a mistake there (wrong launch file) when updating the docs for Electric, sorry! That's fixed now.

Note that wiki pages may have different versions for different ROS releases (C Turtle, Diamondback, Electric) which you select by clicking the button for your release at the top of the page. Be careful you use the right docs.

To add confusion, there are actually two versions of the OpenNI ROS driver in Electric. The old version is the one from Diamondback, which we've preserved for backwards compatibility. So you can actually still follow the Diamondback instructions.

The new driver is a tad experimental, but much more modular and introduces new features. It has a couple of breaking API changes; in particular `/camera/rgb/points` no longer exists, use `/camera/depth_registered/points` instead. See the Quick Start instructions at [openni_launch](http://www.ros.org/wiki/openni_launch).

---

Originally posted by [Patrick Mihelich](https://answers.ros.org/users/180/patrick-mihelich/) with karma: 4336 on 2011-09-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [CaptainTrunky](https://answers.ros.org/users/1038/captaintrunky/) on 2011-09-06**:
Thanks for help, it's became more clear!